# receive 404 error from post request: postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, postman

I am trying to make a post request from postman but I'm receiving a 404 error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 4<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse`.
I have added the `Content-Type: application/json` header and defined the json body in the raw tab.
This is the url: http://localhost:8000/api/signup.
I can't make this post request nor can I access the application in the browser as I receive `cannot GET /api/signup`.

[image]

How can I fix this?

controllers/user.js

```
const User = require('../models/user')
const { errorHandler } = require("../helpers/dbErrorHandler")

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
    console.log("req.body", req.body)
    // signs up new user
 const user = new User(req.body)
 user.save((err, user) => {
if(err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        err: errorHandler(err)
    })
}
res.json({
    user 
 })
 })
}
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

require('dotenv').config()

// import routes
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user')

// app
const app = express()

// connect db - first arg is url (specified in .env)
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useCreateIndex: true
}).then(() => console.log('DB connected'))

// middlewares 
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
// used to save users credentials
app.use(cookieParser())


// routes middleware
app.use('/api', userRoutes)

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

models/user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
...
}, {timestamps: true})



userSchema.methods = {
    encryptPassword: function(password) {
        if (!password) return '';
        // hashes password
        try {
            return crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.salt)
            .update(password)
            .digest('hex')
        } catch (err) {
            return ''
        }
    }
}

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

routes/user.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const { signup} = require('../controllers/user')

router.post('/signup', signup)

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Can you try POST /api/user/signup

Comment: Can you post content of `./routes/user``file?

Comment: I still receive the same error when I POST /api/user/signup. I've updated my question with the code. @Harshal

Comment: Have you try with close postman and reopen then try on new tab

Comment: Can you check if the server is running?

Comment: Do you have index file in routes?

Comment: The server is running but when I try to access it, I receive a 404 error in the terminal: ```GET /api/signup 404 1.858 ms - 149```. I've tried ```/```, ```/api```, ```/api/user/signup```, ```api/signup``` but nothing works. @Harshal

Comment: You have defined the api as POST and you are accessing as GET, try changing method as I said in my answer point #3

Comment: Try same urls with POST methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 means NOT Found,

### May be your URL or Method is wrong

Here is what you can try to diagnose:

1. Check if server is running
2. Check the port and URL you are accessing.
3. Check the postman method **POST** and URL.
4. Check the route, routes file and match it with postman URL

Answer (score 1):

This seems like two different issues, for the POST request, the error seems like there is an invalid string in your JSON payload that your application cannot read and parse.

The second one is mainly due to the route is not found, without looking at your `./routes/user` file, it seems like there are two possibilities:

1. You have a nested route of `/user/...`. If that is the case, try accessing your api via `/api/user/signup` instead of `/api/signup`
2. You did not create a GET route for you `signup` path. Normally signup is a POST path instead of `GET`.

It would be best if you can provide the source code of `./routes/user.js` for us to properly answer this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have provided the code of ./routes/user.js  and the server is running. I don't think I have a nested route of /user/ as accessing the api via /api/user/signup doesn't work. @Kong

Comment: Accessing GET won't work since you define your route as POST. Can you post your payload that causing the JSON error too?

Answer (score 0):

404 error is an HTTP status code that means that the page you were trying to reach on a website couldn't be found on their server. To be clear, the 404 error indicates that while the server itself is reachable, the specific page showing the error is not.

Make sure that your indexing is correct and your local server is running properly.