# Node.js + Express

Tags: node.js, express

I was creating a contact form using nodemailer. I implemented it and it was working fine, but some time later I came back to do a final test in postman it started to give me the following error`"message": Not Found - /contact` and `"stack": "Error: Not Found - /contact\n` . I am not sure what's causing the error.

this is code:

```js
const transport = {
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com', // Don’t forget to replace with the SMTP host of your provider
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // use SSL
  auth: {
    user: process.env.GMAIL,
    pass: process.env.PASSWORD
  }
}

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport)

transporter.verify((error, success) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Server is ready to take messages');
  }
});

app.post('/contact', (req, res, next) => {
  const name = req.body.name
  const email = req.body.email
  const message = req.body.message
  const content = ` name: ${name} \n email: ${email} \n message: ${message} `

  const mail = {
    from: name,
    // to: 'RECEIVING_EMAIL_ADDRESS_GOES_HERE',  // Change to email address that you want to receive messages on
    to: 'xxx@gmail.com', // Change to email address that you want to receive messages on
    subject: 'New Message from Contact Form',
    text: content
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        status: 'fail'
      })
    } else {
      res.json({
        status: 'success'
      })
    }
  })
})
```

[image: Postman output when testing the api]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [receive 404 error from post request: postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61457570/receive-404-error-from-post-request-postman)